# Add get variables to url throung htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

I want to add one get parameter to the every url on my wprdpress website except the index page.

For example,

Consider website name to be www.example.com

If `www.example.com` is hit than nothing should happen

But if I hit `www.example.com/events` than a get parameter viz. "home" be appended to it. Final URL should be as follows:
`www.example.com/events/?home`

I want to use this parameter for further processing.

my current `.htaccess` file contains following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lp-variation-id

RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^landing-page=([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

and i m working on wordpress project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond !^/$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1?home
```

Depending on your hosting environment the URL may or may not start with a slash, so you might have to remove it from the RewriteRule.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. I have added contents of htaccess file to the above question.